# Rendering static folder for an React route

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have some legacy static code ( HTML, CSS, jQuery, JS, etc ) inside a folder. Now, I need to render those content on a specific route in my react application. I cant use an iFrame due to some policy reasons. I dont want to rewrite this in React for two reasons:

- It is a single page with legacy code. Not worth the effort
- This same static folder is also used in other places

So, if I rewrite it in React, then I will end up having two versions: one a react version of the page and the other is a non-react version of the page. If I want a change, then I need to update it twice.

What options do I have? What is the easiest and less messy way to render a static file inside a folder in my react app, without using iFrame?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your static files inside the `public` directory and replicate the path that you need with folders, these files are then statically served. If the route is `/display` you can add a folder called `display`. Lets say your file is called `contact.html`, then your file will be available under `/display/contact.html`.

##### Linking to the file via react

```
// ...
return (
  <a 
    href="/display/contact.html" 
    // if you want to open it in a new tab
    target="_blank" 
  />
);
```

Comment: I already have them in static folder. How do I display their content? If the route is /display, then how do I load the contents of the folder in a new tab?

Comment: Updated the original answer